# JButton does not appear on JDialog

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

I have a problem in this code that is, I have added a `JButton` on `JDialog` but the button is not visible when dialog appears. Please help.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class A implements ActionListener {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();

    public A() {
        JButton b = new JButton("JDialog");
        f.add(b);
        b.addActionListener(this);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(500,500);
    }

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        new A();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JDialog d = new JDialog(f,"Dialog",true);
        d.setSize(100,100);
        d.setVisible(true);
        d.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JButton b  = new JButton("OK");
        d.add(b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding it before you call `setVisible`

Answer (score 2):

add button before calling to `setvisible(true)`.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class A implements ActionListener {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    public A() {


        JButton b = new JButton("JDialog");
        f.add(b);
        b.addActionListener(this);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(500,500);
    }

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        new A();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JDialog d = new JDialog(f,"Dialog",true);
        d.setSize(100,100);

        d.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JButton b  = new JButton("OK");
        d.add(b);
        d.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your `Component` is rendered before you add your button to it. Try adding the button before you render your `Component`. Try to add it before you call `setVisible` or `repaint` your `Component`.